# How do I use an array within JSON as my data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSON object and within that is a 2D array that has the data I need to visualise in it.

How can I pull only the array stored in 'datapoints' from the following JSON?

```
var myData = [
    {"target": "tar.get",
        "datapoints": [
            [71.0, 1443793200],
            [119.0, 1443793500],
            [75.0, 1443793800],
            [106.0, 1443794100],
            [93.0, 1443794400],
            [105.0, 1443794700],
            [87.0, 1443795000],
            [72.0, 1443795300],
            [39.0, 1443795600],
            [78.0, 1443795900],
            [48.0, 1443796200],
            [74.0, 1443796500],
            [61.0, 1443796800],
            [86.0, 1443797100],
            [75.0, 1443797400],
            [79.0, 1443797700],
            [69.0, 1443798000],
            [69.0, 1443798300],
            [78.0, 1443798600],
            [71.0, 1443798900],
            [45.0, 1443799200],
            [68.0, 1443799500],
            [57.0, 1443799800],
            [null, 1443800100]]
    }];
```

Comment: `myData[0]['datapoints']`

Comment: Better not access properties by string like this. You'd better of doing: `myData[0].datapoints`. See [this](https://jslinterrors.com/a-is-better-written-in-dot-notation).

Comment: You only want to use `['something']` is if the property starts with a number or if you're using a minifier. Your average program should use `.something`

Answer (score 2):

Read some beginners guides to JSON like [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) to know the basics.

You can access it like this:

```
myData[0].datapoints;
```

You probably want to look through the `mydata` array like this:

```
var i;
for (i = 0; i < myData.length; i++) {
    var datapoints = myData[index].datapoints;
    // do stuff with datapoints
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access JSON members as any JS object:

```
var datapoints = myData[0].datapoints;
```

Comment: The important thing to remember is that there is no such thing as "JSON objects". They're just normal objects.